# How to find the first occurring string_view in another string_view?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++23, string-view

I have written the following function that aims to find the first occurring string_view in the `cli_option` string_view and if finds any, it returns an iterator to the matched string in the array called `cli_options`.

Here is an MRE:

```
#include <array>
#include <string_view>
#include <algorithm>


namespace
{

// Define the array of CLI options
constexpr std::array<std::string_view, 9> cli_options {"--help", "--version", "--init-file=",
                                                       "-d", "-f", /*...*/};

}


auto check_cli_option(const std::string_view cli_option) noexcept
{
    // happy path
    for ( auto it { std::cbegin( cli_options ) }; it < std::cend( cli_options ); ++it )
    {
        const auto& supported_cli_option { *it };
        if ( cli_option.starts_with( supported_cli_option ) )
        {
            return it;
        }
    }

    // unhappy path
    // If no match is found, check which option occurs first in cli_option
    auto pos_of_first_occurring_option { std::string_view::npos };
    auto iter_to_first_occurring_option { std::cend( cli_options ) };

    for ( auto it { std::cbegin( cli_options ) }; it < std::cend( cli_options ); ++it )
    {
        const auto& supported_cli_option { *it };
        if ( const auto pos { cli_option.find( supported_cli_option ) };
             pos < pos_of_first_occurring_option )
        {
            pos_of_first_occurring_option = pos;
            iter_to_first_occurring_option = it;
        }
    }

    return iter_to_first_occurring_option;
}
```

The `cli_option` needs to start with one of the items in the array to be considered a valid option. Otherwise, the function starts the second loop to find which one occurs first (if any). So an input like **"-d"** or **"-duncic43"** is valid but **"--d"** or **"3$F-d"** or **"d-d-f"** etc are invalid even though `-d` is included in all of them. So in short any junk is allowed to follow the option. The junk characters must not precede the option itself though.

I also combined the two for loops but the compiler for some reason generates more code (and probably less efficient?) for that version of the function. I guess I won't use that one.

**The question is:** Can this be simplified? Especially by using a standard algorithm. I looked at [`std::find_first_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find_first_of) but that is not intended for searching for multiple strings in a single string.

Comment: What exactly does your second `for`-loop do? If it can't be found in the first loop, doesn't it mean it's not valid anyway?

Comment: @康桓瑋 Yes it's not valid. But the function should still return the iterator to the first occurring supported option so the call site can show it to the user of the program in an error message like "Unrecognized option '-duncic43'; did you mean '-d'?". That's the aim.

Comment: I do not get it what this code suppose to do. Based on text description I've wrote some test, but it fails: https://godbolt.org/z/zPd1d1h5W Please fix test so is unambiguous what this code suppose to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By adopting test to provided code and ignoring text description I got nice equivalent code which uses C++20 ranges:

```cpp
auto check_cli_option(const std::string_view cli_option) noexcept
{
    return std::ranges::min_element(cli_options, std::less<>{}, [cli_option] (auto option) {
        return cli_option.find(option);
    });
    if (cli_option.find(*it) != std::string_view::npos) return it;
    return std::cend(cli_options);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/EEE4az7nr

Still this logic is strange so I'm not happy with it.

Comment: This looks pretty decent and neat. However, what happens if none of the valid cli_options can be found in `cli_option`? What does this algorithm return in that case? I want it to return `std::cend(cli_options)` to indicate that nothing could be matched.

Comment: Testcase added and fixed.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to check whether `cli_option` starts with one of the `cli_options` and if that's not the case, check if you find any valid option within `cli_option` and return the first one. These two cases can be done together, by iterating over smaller and smaller substrings of `cli_option`:

```
auto check_cli_option(const std::string_view cli_option) noexcept {
    for (auto it = cli_option.cbegin(); it < cli_option.cend(); ++it) {
        std::string_view cli_option_end{it, cli_option.cend()};
        
        for (const auto& valid_option : cli_options) {
            if (cli_option_end.starts_with(valid_option)) {
                return &valid_option;
            }
        }
    }

    return cli_options.cend();
}
```